# Pick date and time from datetimePicker in Selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium, datetimepicker

I am using JAVA Selenium in order to pick a date and then a time from a datetimePicker element. Once you click on this later the current time appears in the list and I need to use next or previous button multiple time until the desired time element is visible, so click on it. Could someone please help me how to write the code that either click on next or previous depending on the displayed list of times until 10:00 is visible then click. Please see the type of calendar

Thank you in advance.

[image: Calendar Type]

```
// Element of date and time  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("Calendar_Location")).click();
List<WebElement> dateList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("Calendar_table_Location"));

int daysCount = dateList.size();
WebElement DesiredTime = null, MidN = null;
Boolean C = false;

for (int i = 1; i <= daysCount; i++) {
    if (C == true)
        break;

    for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
        String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Date_Location[" + i + "]/td[" + j + "]")).getText();
        System.out.println("The text is " + text);
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("19")) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("Date_Location[" + i + "]/td[" + j + "]")).click();
            System.out.println("Found");
            while (isElementPresent(DesiredTime, driver) == false) {
                if (isElementPresent(MidN, driver) == true) 
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("Arrow_next")).click();
                else
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("Arrow_previous")).click();
            }

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("Location of desired time")).click();
            C = true;

            break;
        }
    }
}

\\isElementPresent() Method
public static boolean isElementPresent(WebElement Element, WebDriver D) {
    try {
        Element = D.findElement(By.xpath("Location"));
        return true;
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried and URL also

Comment: Hello, I have shared the code I have tried. It works fine for the date as the code will always pick a date from the current month. But the issue I am facing is picking a time. If the desired time is not visible. I don't know how to click arrow_up (previous) or arrow_down (next).

Comment: Can we have some HTML for the input field ? or possibly page url if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following steps,

```
/*
* Steps :
* 1] click 10 o clock is displaying or not
* 2] if not, get the current displaying time (center one)
* 3] if the displaying time is lesser than 8 click down arrow button 6 times to display 10 o clock
* 4] if the displaying time is greater than 18, click up arrow 6 time to display 10 o clock
* 5] then click on the 10 o clock
* */
public void clickTime(String displayTimeExactly){
    By time = By.xpath("//span[text()='"+displayTimeExactly+"']");
    boolean timeIsDisplaying = true;

    // checking 10:00 is displaying or not
    try{
        driver.findElement(time).click();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        timeIsDisplaying = false;
    }

    // navigating to 10:00
    if(!timeIsDisplaying){
        // currently 6 time is displaying
        // take one displaying date
        By displayingTimeXpath = By.xpath("//capture displaying time xpath");
        String displayingTime[] =  driver.findElement(displayingTimeXpath).getText().split(":");
        int displayingTIme = Integer.parseInt(displayingTime[0]);
        if(displayingTIme < 8){
            //click down arrow 6 times
        }else if(displayingTIme > 18){
            //click up arrow 6 times
        }

        // clicking the time now
        driver.findElement(time).click();
    }


}
```